# Rotate an element an a fixed axis

Tags: javascript, css, animation

[image]

Any way to achieve something like this in CSS/JS or GSAP ?

Comment: css animation `rotateZ()` with keyframes

Comment: don't tell me that you found nothing about this trivial animation on google? come on .. a little effort please ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple CSS example

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 5px);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10em;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  transform-origin: left center;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of achieving this is to create a rotation keyframe, that uses `transform: rotateZ`. Make sure to set the `transform-origin` to `left center`, so that the "needle" div rotates around its left part (and not around its center).

```css
.needle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  border-radius: 40px;
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: rotation 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  from {
    transform: rotateZ(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="needle"></div>
</div>
```